# How to use icu4j RuleBasedNumberFormat with a custom locale?

Tags: java, locale, icu4j

I read through the [javadoc](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html) but, I honestly I don't understand how to use the RuleBasedNumberFormat with a custom locale. I understand how it compute the number into text, but I don't know how to make for my locale.

Comment: the constructor already takes Locale as parameter. http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html#RuleBasedNumberFormat(java.util.Locale,%20int) . What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: The issue is, how to use the class with a locale that is not available for them. Example, they don't have the locale ms for malay.

Comment: Hi BaimAT - can you explain carefully in your question what the exact problem is that you are facing? If you include code examples of what you have tried so far and why they haven't worked, that would be useful too.